# Checkbox to .detach and then .prepend object

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, prepend, detach

I want to use .detach and .prepend with a checkbox, I found this function that uses it with two buttons:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x;
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        x = $("p").detach();
    });
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("body").prepend(x);
    });
});
```

But how can I use it with a check box? And when the checkbox is checked it prepend the elemento to the body, and when is unchecked detach the element.

Right now I am using fade in and fade out, but I want to change that to detach and prepend:

```
$('#toggle').change(function () {
    if (!this.checked) 
    //  ^
    $('.content').fadeOut('slow');
        else 
    $('.content').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: prepend to what? `body`?

Comment: Yeah, it could be body.

Comment: But as i can see it, why don't you try to just replace your first code with relevant event and selector???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:-

```js
var x;
$('#toggle').change(function() {
  if (!this.checked)
    x = $('.content').detach();
  else
    $('body').append(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   

<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" checked="true" />

<div class="content">
  content content content content content content content content content content content content
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much BenG, it worked perfectly!
It is possible to leave the default state of the div "prepend" and when I check the box show it?
I am new to javascritp and jQuery, still learning how events and selectors work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/CZojXXm7eYsCIeEv4Z4Q) example helps you get a clarity.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var p;
      $("#trigger").change(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
          $('#mydiv').prepend(p);
          p = null;
        } else {
          p = $("p").detach();
        }
      });
    });
      p {
        background: yellow;
        margin: 6px 0;
      }
      p.off {
        background: black;
      }
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>detach demo</title>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="mydiv">
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>you?</p>
      </div>
      Toggle:
      <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="trigger" checked/>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
  var myCheck = $('input[name=myCheck]'),
      content = $('#content');
  myCheck.change(function(){
    if (myCheck.is(':checked')) {
      content.prependTo(document.body);
    } else {      
      content.detach();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content"><span>Content</span></div>
  <label for="myCheck">
    <input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" checked="true">
    <span>My Check</span>
  </label>  
</body>
</html>
```